# Does ROS 1 have compatibility with any Renesas Hardware? Or is it just available for ROS-micro (ROS 2)?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-melodic, ros2, hardware

I'm doing research about ROS compatibility with different microcontroller hardware. From what I've searched, I have only found compatibility with microcontrollers using micro-ROS, which is built with ROS 2. However, I'd like to use a microcontroller (produced by Renesas) with ROS 1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

micro-ROS for ROS 2 is the successor to `rosserial` for ROS 1. Although the tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials) focus on Arduino, [plenty of other devices are supported](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial), and you can always [add something custom](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Adding%20Support%20for%20New%20Hardware).

If that doesn't meet your needs, it's always possible to come up with a custom protocol to communicate with an interfacing node on your host computer: for example, a node that reads from a USB Serial port connected to the microcontroller can provide that data to the rest of the ROS system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, How do I know which renesas devices are supported with ROS 1?

Comment: If you don't see it in the list that I linked (on the main wiki page), then it's not officially supported. However, the point of rosserial is that it's very easy to add support for new devices. So, since I don't see an existing integration, I would implement the two functions as described by the third link, and then you should be up and running pretty quickly.